# How to evaluate multiple rows based on a column

Tags: hive, hiveql

Table ActualTO(60000+ records daily increment) have columns rid, caid & consent .rid is primary key.there will be multiple unique caid's corresponding to each rid.consent Column contains either consented or not-consented. How to add a new column which contains list caid's which are not-consented corresponding to each rid.

Rid caid  consent new_col.

```
1001 qc101 consented qc102;qc111
1001 qc102 notconsented qc102;qc111
1001 qc111 notconsented qc102;qc111
1221 qc244 notconsented qc244;qc201
1221 qc202 consented qc244;qc201
1221 qc201 notconsented qc244;qc201
```